# Difference between 2 simple DTD declarations

Tags: xml, dtd

Could someone explain the difference between the following DTD statements?

```
<!ELEMENT all (book+, dvd+)>
```

and

```
<!ELEMENT all (book, dvd)+>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content model (book+, dvd+) matches a sequence of elements:  first, one or more book elements (that's `book+`), then (that's `,`) one or more dvd elements (that's `dvd+`).  So the following match this content model:

1. `<book/><dvd/>`
2. `<book/><book/><book/><dvd/>`
3. `<book/><dvd/><dvd/><dvd/><dvd/><dvd/>`
4. `<book/><book/><book/><book/><dvd/><dvd/>`

etc.

The content model (book, dvd)+ matches one or more occurrences of the sequence consisting of one book followed by one dvd.  So the following match it:

1. `<book/><dvd/>`
2. `<book/><dvd/><book/><dvd/>`
3. `<book/><dvd/><book/><dvd/><book/><dvd/>`
4. `<book/><dvd/><book/><dvd/><book/><dvd/><book/><dvd/>`

etc.

The difference is that in the first expression, the two + operators apply to the individual element names book and dvd; in the second, the + applies to the sequence (book, dvd) as a whole.

Note that the first example in each list is legal under both content models, and that none of the others are.

Answer (score 0):

With 0 knowledge of dtd's:

I'd say the first one should contain at least 1 book **AND** 1 dvd. But may contain many books and/or dvd's.

The second one contains should contain at least 1 book **OR** 1 dvd. But may contain many books and/or dvd's.

Comment: Sorry, wrong answer.  Both must contain at least one book and at least one dvd.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen Are you sure? Hmm. Ok, if you say so. How about this theory: the first one should contain at least 1 book and 1 DVD. The second one too, but should have the same amount of DVD's as books?